# jQuery UI droppable plain text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a requirement to drag and drop text from outside of browser to web page, but I would like to use jQuery UI droppable to accept pure text.

Here is a tutorial which uses javascript and this works for me:

http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/

But I am dynamically adding some elements and making them droppable using liveQuery and few other stuff which would be fairly complicated to implement.

I tried something like, it works fine for draggable elements but not for plain text:

```
        $('#cointainer').livequery(function () {
            $(this).droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {

                    alert("dropped");
                },
                greedy: true
            });
        });
```

Is it possible to do it with jQuery UI droppable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is closest I got, it uses jQuery but **not jQuery UI droppable**. Hack around is to wrap whatever you need to do in function and the bind this code and jQuery droppable on same element and call same function from both drop events. This way you can support both droppable elements and text dropping.

```
        $('#cointainer').livequery(function () {

            $(this).bind('dragover', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
            });


            $(this).bind('dragenter', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $(this).bind('drop', function (e) {

                e.preventDefault(); // prevent redirect

                if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text') == ':)') {
                    $(this).append('<div>You dropped a smile!</div>');
                }

                e.stopPropagation(); // prevent bubbling, without this we would get duplicate items if parent is droppable too, acts like jQuery greedy: true;
            });
        });
```